# Problema con animaciones de JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animación

He estado teniendo problemas con Jquery y su api de *Effects*, tengo una alerta que quiero que aparezca y se desaparezca usando la animación `hide` cada vez que se le indique llamando al siguiente método:

```javascript
const drawAlert = (content) => {
 $('#alertContainer').html(
     '<div class="content-one">' +
         '<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>' +
     '</div>' +

     '<div class="content-two">' +
         '<p>' +
             content +
         '</p>' +
     '</div>'
 )
 
 setTimeout(() => {
     $('#alertContainer').hide("slow")
     console.debug("se ejecuta")
 }, 4000);
}
```

El contenedor donde quiero dibujar la alerta:

```javascript
<!-- Jquey version:
      <script    
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" 
              integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" 
              crossorigin="anonymous">
          </script>  -->

      <div class="alert-booking" id="alertContainer">
                  <!-- <div class="content-one">
                      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                  </div>
  
                  <div class="content-two">
                      <p>
                         Content
                      </p>
                  </div> -->
              </div>
```

Y su css:

```css
.alert-booking{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    right: 0;
    width: 30%;
    height: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 80;
}
```

El problema es que veo que se presenta en la pantalla, pero al momento de ejecutar la función hide no se ejecuta la animación y desaparece de forma estática osea sin la animación, y también el navegador no reconoce algunos métodos como seria el de *slideUp()*, *slideDown()*, etc... Lo que quiero es que me digan es si el código que presente tiene alguna falla o se debería hacer de otra forma para poder logar que la animación se ejecute después de 4 segundos, gracias de antemano.

```js
const drawAlert = (content) => {
 $('#alertContainer').html(
     '<div class="content-one">' +
         '<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>' +
     '</div>' +

     '<div class="content-two">' +
         '<p>' +
             content +
         '</p>' +
     '</div>'
 )
 
 setTimeout(() => {
     $('#alertContainer').hide("slow")
     console.debug("se ejecuta")
 }, 4000);
}
drawAlert('Contenido de la alerta');
```

```css
.alert-booking {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    right: 0;
    width: 30%;
    height: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 80;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" 
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

El contenedor donde quiero dibujar la alerta:


      <div class="alert-booking" id="alertContainer">
                  <!-- <div class="content-one">
                      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                  </div>
  
                  <div class="content-two">
                      <p>
                         Content
                      </p>
                  </div> -->
              </div>
```

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para agregar al final un fragmento de código ejecutable donde se ve que sí funciona la animación. Revisa la consola para ver si hay algún error en tus scripts.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias.